# Как запустить счётчик таймера на JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Имеется простой таймер, который при старте страницы должен убывать. Он почему-то не убывает. Возможно, js прописан некорректно?

```js
var timer = 60;
var interval = setInterval(function() {
  timer--;
  $('.timer').text(timer);
  if (timer === 0) clearInterval(interval);
}, 1000);
```

```css
body {
  background: #222;
}

.timer {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="timer">60</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы jQuery не подключили, либо с элементом "$('.timer')" стоит взаимодействовать через нативный js

```js
var timer = 60;
var interval = setInterval(function(){
    timer--;
    $('.timer').text(timer);
    if (timer === 0) clearInterval(interval);
}, 1000);
```

```css
body {
  background: #222;
}

.timer {
    font-size: 2.5em;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="timer">60</div>
```

Comment: Оффтоп: при редактирование кода в сниппете есть кнопка "привести в порядок"- убирает лишние отступы.

Answer (score 1):

Вместо `timer--;` можно сразу `$('.timer').text(--timer);`

```js
var timer = 60;
var interval = setInterval(function()
{
  $('.timer').text(--timer);
  if (timer === 0) clearInterval(interval);
}, 1000);
```

```css
<style>
body {
  background: #222;
}

.timer {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #ccc;
}
</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="timer">60</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script>
var countDownDate = new Date("Sep 30, 2018 0:0:0").getTime();
var x = setInterval(function() {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var distance = countDownDate - now;
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML ="<b>Timer<br></b> "+ days + " days " + hours +" hours "
    + minutes + " minutes  " + seconds + " seconds ";
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Discount not Actived";
    }
}, 1000);
</script>
```

любой дата и время напиши здесь и все

```
 var countDownDate = new Date("Sep 30, 2018 0:0:0").getTime();
```